# Upgrade jdk version in websphere application

Tags: websphere, websphere-6.1

I am trying to upgrade the jdk version on websphere application server, can someone please help me on the steps.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can download SDK fix packs from [Recommended fixes for WebSphere Application Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg27004980).  It is not possible to make arbitrary updates to the level of Java (that is, it is not possible to run Java 6 or 7 on WebSphere Application Server 6.1).